# AVX2/VCL : static/dynamic lane scheduling

Tags: c++, simd, sse, avx2, vector-class-library

I have been trying to speed up a binary tree evaluation algo using AVX2. Actually, I'm using Agner's VCL lib since the difference between hand-coding the algo and using vcl was small for big gain in readability.

I have a list of trees that need to be evaluated. I put the list of indexes in an array 'vTreeIndexes'. This is the static scheduling part. As soon as a lane is done, I collect its result using a mask then I load new indexes using vTreeIndexes.

```
// detect finished lanes
const vcl::Vec8ib mask = (nodeIndex < zero); // nodeIndex holds 8 indexes to some nodes from 8 different trees. When an index is negative, the tree has been evaluated
// get compact mask
const __mmask8    k    = vcl::to_bits(mask);
// load next 8 indexes from static scheduling array
vcl::Vec8i nextIndexes;
nextIndexes.load(vTreeIndexes + nextTreeIndex);
// load shuffle mask
const vcl::Vec8i shuffleVector(ShuffleHelper::loadMasks[k]);
// shuffle (1)
nextIndexes = vcl::lookup8(shuffleVector, nextIndexes);
// replace finished lanes
nodeIndex = vcl::select(mask, nextIndexes, nodeIndex);
```

(1) : we have 8 tree indexes T0, T1, ... T7 in 'nextIndexes'.
Some lanes are finished (let's say lanes 2 and 5 are finished) so we want T0 to be shuffled to lane 2 and T1 to be shuffled to lane 5. The other indexes, we don't care. The mask will only replace the finished lanes 2 and 5.

This part works well, now building on this approach, I want to introduce "dynamic scheduling", ie, when a tree finishes its evaluation it may indicate the need to evaluate 2 more "conditional trees". So I now need to "blend" static and dynamic scheduling, and this is where things are not great.

My first working solution uses another C array to hold temporary "pending" trees :

```
// part1 - load continuation trees and store them in pendingFifo
//
// load "continuation trees"
vcl::Vec8i        continuationTrees = vcl::lookup<16384>(prevNodeIndex, vNodeContinuationTrees);
// check which one are set
const vcl::Vec8ib continuationMask  = continuationTrees > zero;
const __mmask8    continuationK     = vcl::to_bits(continuationMask);
const int         nbContinuations   = __builtin_popcount(continuationK);
// "pack left" : move the non-zero one on the left, the zero one on the right
const vcl::Vec8i  packLeftShuffleVector(ShuffleHelper::packLeftMasks[continuationK]);
continuationTrees                       = vcl::lookup8(packLeftShuffleVector, continuationTrees);
// each index holds a left continuation
const vcl::Vec8i leftContinuationTrees  = continuationTrees & 0x0FFFF;
// and a right continuation
const vcl::Vec8i rightContinuationTrees = continuationTrees >> 16;
// concat all those indexes in the pendingFifo array
leftContinuationTrees.store(pendingFifo.data() + pendingTail);
rightContinuationTrees.store(pendingFifo.data() + pendingTail + nbContinuations);
pendingTail += nbContinuations * 2;

// part 2 : priority1 : load from pendingFifo array, priority 2 : complete from static scheduling array
// see how much elements we're going to load from each array
const int availableInPending    = pendingTail - pendingHead;
const int loadedFromPending     = std::min(availableInPending, nbFinishedTrees);
const int loadedFromNextIndexes = nbFinishedTrees - loadedFromPending; // the complement

// prepare some shift / mask
const vcl::Vec8i  shift     = id - loadedFromPending; // id is the vector {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
const vcl::Vec8ib blendMask = (shift < zero);

// load from pending
vcl::Vec8i nextIndexesFromPending;
nextIndexesFromPending.load(pendingFifo.data() + pendingHead);
// we keep only the first 'loadedFromPending' elements
nextIndexesFromPending = vcl::select(blendMask, nextIndexesFromPending, zero);

// load from statically scheduled
vcl::Vec8i nextIndexesFromScheduled;
nextIndexesFromScheduled.load(vScheduledTreeIndexes + nextTreeIndex);
// we right-shift the vector by loadedFromPending and zero out the first loadedFromPending elements
nextIndexesFromScheduled = vcl::select(~blendMask, vcl::lookup8(shift, nextIndexesFromScheduled), zero);

// that way we can concat both vectors together, having
// - loadedFromPending elements from pending on the left, and 
// - 8-loadedFromPending elements from scheduled on the right
vcl::Vec8i nextIndexes = nextIndexesFromPending | nextIndexesFromScheduled;

// and as before we shuffle this vector to replace the finished lanes
const vcl::Vec8i loadShuffleVector(ShuffleHelper::loadMasks[k]);
nextIndexes = vcl::lookup8(loadShuffleVector, nextIndexes);
nodeIndex = vcl::select(mask, nextIndexes, nodeIndex);
```

This code works, but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution out there.
I've been trying to replace the pendingFifo array by using a vector variable (that maybe could stay in a register), but this is slower.
Probably the way I "blend" the indexes together is no good.
I'm pretty new to vector programming, any hint on how to improve the above solution welcome !

PS : direct intel intrinsics usage welcome as well

Comment: At first glance seems like a similar problem to SIMD Mandelbrot, except in that case you can keep iterating an "escaped" point without harm, no risk of segfaults like your gather loads.  If you're already using `__mmask8`, can you use other AVX-512 masking features to mask your loads, maybe only checking every few iterations if it's time to replace some elements that have reached the end of their chain of pointers?

Comment: Are you refering to https://github.com/skeeto/mandel-simd ? I'm not sure I see what you're referring to in the code ?

Also, maybe my question is not clear enough : what I think is not efficient is
- the use of a c array to hold the pending "continuation trees". I should be able to replace it with a Vec32s or a Vec16s.
- the way I fill the pending c array using 2 overlapping stores
- the way I then create nextIndexes by blending elements from the pending array and the scheduled array (shift + mask)

This code is approx twice as slow as the "static scheduling only" version.

Comment: I think I guessed wrong about how your code works; I didn't take the time to really understand it, just kind of guessed how it might work from skimming the text, picturing tree traversal via pointers. Sorry about that.